# Increasing StaticDisplayLevels in SharePoint Online increases Response time for the page

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, response

Recently I changed StaticDisplayLevels from 3 to 5 in MasterPage of SharePoint Online.

Due to this Response time of page drastically increased from 15sec to 56sec (Big Difference).

Could anyone explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

the StaticDisplayLevels property is to specify the number of menu levels to display in a static menu. All menu levels below the specified value are displayed in a dynamic menu. Since you are increasing the number of menu levels to display it is taking more time to load and hence more response time.

Comment: but, why the response time difference is so big?

Comment: It all depend on the menu size and functionality what it performs which take times to load. the extra menu which you are loading that might be having more customized behaviour to perform and hence you more response time to load. Also to note you are changing the defaultproperty of StaticDisplayLevel. Microsoft kept it as 3 because they were aware of the response time difference.